# expected unqualified id before int j. I know it might be off topic but i cant find the error

Tags: c++, xcode

```
#include <iostream>




using namespace std;


int main () 


{
        for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++)

{

        cout << '\t' << i; // \t represent a tab character, which will format our output nice;y


}

       cout << '\n';


       for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)


       cout << i;
}

       (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)


       cout <<'\t' << i * j;
}

       cout << '\n';
}

}
```

Comment: Very little code, multiple errors. Count your braces (`{}`) and check your `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

'for' keyword is missing and there are lot of error in braces. I would suggest use of proper indentation for avoiding such errors

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the for keyword in the loop using j.